# Can Some one explain me "onScroll" with "Animated.event"?

Tags: javascript, react-native, animation, react-native-animatable

Can someone explain me this react native docs in Animated.event in onScroll? Or just could provide me a link to it's refs, plz. Shouldn't I be passing a function to the onScroll (event) =>  {Some function}?

```
onScroll={Animated.event(
       [{nativeEvent: {contentOffset: {x: this._scrollX}}}],
       {listener: (event) => console.log(event)}, // Optional async listener
     )}
```

Other thing, is the Animated.Value in this._scrollX receiving the x value of contentOffset? how come?

https://reactnative.dev/docs/animated#event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gestures, like panning or scrolling, and other events can map directly to animated values using **Animated.event()** which triggers when you scroll (in your case). The first level is an array to allow mapping across multiple args, and that array contains nested objects.

**For example**, when working with horizontal scrolling gestures, you would do the following in order to map **event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x** to **this._scrollX** (should be Animated.Value) without having to setState and re-render the component hierarchy. This is done in an optimized way that is faster than calling setState and re-rendering.

Reference:
https://reactnative.dev/docs/animations#animated-api

Answer (score 0):

Here maybe your answer. It contains 2 types of onscroll function handle

[How does Animated.Event work in React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43510145/how-does-animated-event-work-in-react-native)